# What is the standard implementation for this compound observer (if any)?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming

I am struggling to find the standard implementation for a very basic observer that late binds and hosts other observers in it.

```
public class CompoundObserver<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public readonly List<IObserver<T>> observers;
    public CompoundObserver()
    {
        this.observers = new List<IObserver<T>>();
    }
    public void Register(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        this.observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        this.observers.ForEach(observer =>
        {
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        this.observers.ForEach(observer =>
        {
            observer.OnError(error);
        });
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        this.observers.ForEach(observer =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(value);
        });
    }
}
```

What is the standard mechanism for something like this in RX .NET?

Comment: can you give an example how would you use it? What about Concat or Merge functions?